# Consultation python in csv .20 major movements by department

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

I need to get the 20 biggest 'MOV12' for 'DPTO', using python and pandas

I have a csv (.del) with the following fields

```
"CODCLI" "DPTO" "SEG" "TIPPER"  "MOV12" 

11 20 "SEG1" "NAT" 6480.00  
19 20 "SEG1" "NAT" 0.00 
28 20 "SEG1" "NAT" 900.00 
29 24 "SEG4" "NAT" 1800.00 
31 20 "SEG1" "NAT" 3050.00 
38 20 "SEG1" "NAT" 0.00 
39 20 "SEG1" "NAT" 0.00
```

I have a csv with the following fields, considering that the 'DPTO' is a total of 12 and I have thousands of data

for the moment and managed to obtain the moyor 'MOV12'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("c.del", sep = ' ') 
result=df.loc[df[['MOV12']].idxmax().unique()].groupby('DPTO')
print(result)
```

I hope you give me suggestions to find the solution, thanks

Comment: use ```series.nlargest```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `apply` with `nlargest`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("c.del", sep = ' ')
result=df.groupby('DPTO').apply(
    lambda x: x.nlargest(20,'MOV12')
)
```

This will find the rows corresponding to the 20 largest values of 'MOV12' for every value of 'DPTO'.

Comment: Do this before you call groupby. I've edited the post.

Comment: again thanks, just throw me the results of 4 DPTO and there are 24 in total, which will be happening

Comment: If you are giving me the result, but in the console they were summarized, I realized

Comment: ```result.to_csv('new_csv_file.csv')```